# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Server.getSecurePhrase is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I really need help here. I have defined a function in connection.js can try to call it in from login.jsx but when I look in the browser console it gave me **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Server.getSecurePhrase is not a function** . Can anyone let me know what is wrong with my code. Thanks.

login.jsx

```
import Server from "../connection/connection";

const Login = () => {

const onSubmit = async (data) => {
   console.log("data is",data)
      Server.getSecurePhrase(data).then(securePhrase => {
      setSecurePhrase(securePhrase)
   })
  }
}
```

and this is in connection.js

```
async getSecurePhrase(data) {
        console.log("Connection: getSecurePhrase");
        return axios
        .post(
          "url is here", data
          
        )
      
              .then(responseJson => {
                console.log("res: ", responseJson);
               
                return responseJson.data.security_phrase;
              })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("Res: ", error);
          return "NULL";
        }); 
}
```

Comment: how are you exporting getSecurePhrase? export default getSecurePhrase?

Comment: in getSecurePhase return await axios.post(...) instead of return axios.post(...)

Comment: @keysl getSecurePhrase is place in functional component named **Server**. That is why I import it in login.jsx

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky tried that but didn't work

Comment: hmm Its kinda hard to see can you add the whole Server or atleast the minimal of it. If its a functional component you shouldn't be able to access it like that

Comment: @keysl Meaning that, I can't access the getSecurePhrase() because it is in Server component? The reason I create Server component is because I would like to centralize any function that call to api.